# Pass parameters from JavaScript function to JSP

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp, parameters

I need to pass a variable from a javascript function to a jsp page. I need to use the parameter in the JSP page for an SQL Query Any way this can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the JSP page is generated server side, when Javascript is exectued client side. The only way to do that is to have a request (either get or post) sent from the browser to your server with the variable in it. So easiest way, something like `<a href="thejsppage.jsp?variablename=addthevalueherewithjavascript">go there</a>`. You can also do that with a POST request and an hidden field in the form.

If you want to avoid reloading the page, you will need to use AJAX.